# Trying to create a polymer app

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit, firebase-polymer

I am trying to make a polymer app which has to pages. One with the cards containing student name and picture and the other page for when we click their card it shows full details.
I tried meteor and polymer. Too many errors. Is there any way to dynamically get data from the db to make the details page when student's card(36 students) is clicked?

Are there any other backend frameworks which works smoothly with polymer?

Apologize for asking a board question but there are only a handfull of tutorials on polymer online.

Answer (score 1):

Check this contacts app, it's similar to what you'r asking:
https://github.com/robdodson/contacts-app

Any beckend can work with Polymer, use Polymer's iron-ajax to make backend calls.

Here are few tutorials, but there are menu more:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/polymer-summit

Polycasts with Rob Dodson

Answer (score 0):

Polymer not expect something special from backend frameworks. For general purpose app you can go with Express.js. It has good documentation and a lot of answers on stack overflow.